# Caption Fontsize Bigger than Text

Tags: captions, fontsize

I am having a problem with the document I am compiling. Until recently everything was working fine but then the text fontsize got smaller and the figure caption fontsize remained the same. I have included a MWE. Is this normal at 11pt?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\raggedbottom
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatletter
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage[top=3 cm,bottom=2.5 cm,left=3 cm,right=3 cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\mtcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage{\pagestyle{plain}\mtcleardoublepage}}
\makeatletter
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.01mm}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{csquotes}%%autostyle
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{etoc}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{tabularx, array, arydshln, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Ας επιλέξουμε αρχικά την τιμή $K=10$ για το σύστημα. Στην περίπτωση αυτή η κατανομή 
 $P\left( s_M^{(j)} \right)$ που αναμένεται είναι {\en{Gauss}} διότι ο χώρος των φάσεων του συστήματος καλύπτεται εξ{\en{'}}ολοκλήρου από χαοτική θάλασσα, πράγμα το οποίο μεταφράζεται στο ότι το σύστημα είναι εργοδικό. Συνεπώς μοιάζει λογική η επιλογή $q\to 1$ ώστε να γίνει η περιγραφή του συστήματος, διότι για $q\to 1 \Rightarrow \exp_q x  \to \exp x$ και συνεπώς το πλαίσιο στατιστικής μηχανικής που περιγράφει κατάλληλα το σύστημα είναι {\en{Boltzmann-Gibbs}}. Με τον τρόπο αυτό η $q$-{\en{Gauss}} γράφεται:
  \begin{equation}
  P\left( s_M^{(j)} \right) \propto \exp_q\left( -\beta s_M^{(j)2} \right)      \Leftrightarrow P\left( s_M^{(j)} \right)\propto \exp\left( -\beta s_M^{(j)2}     \right)
  \end{equation}
και δεν είναι άλλη από την κατανομή {\en{Gauss}}.
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}
   \caption{\textit{Γράφημα του χώρου των φάσεων της \textbf{(\ref{st1})} για $K=10$ \cite{tirnakli}. Με μαύρες κουκίδες σημειώνονται οι περιοχές χαοτικής δυναμικής. Είναι προφανές πως σε ολόκληρο το επίπεδο $[0,2\pi]\times [0,2\pi]$ κυριαρχεί χάος.}}\label{gaus11}
   \end{center}
 \end{figure}
  \par Για την κανονικοποίηση δουλεύουμε με τον ακόλουθο τρόπο: Παίρνοντας     $\bar{P}\left( \bar{s}_M^{(j)} \right)=P(0) \exp\left( -\bar{\beta} \bar{s}_M^{(j)2} \right)$ και επιβάλλοντας τους μετασχηματισμούς:
  \begin{equation}
  P\left( s_M^{(j)} \right)=\frac{\bar{P}\left( \bar{s}_M^{(j)} \right)}     {P(0)}, \quad y=P(0)\bar{s}_M^{(j)}, \quad \beta=\bar{\beta}\left[        P(0)\right]^2
 \end{equation}
 καταλήγουμε στη ακόλουθη έκφραση:
 \begin{equation}
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P\left( s_M^{(j)} \right)ds_M^{(j)}=\int_{-     \infty}^{\infty}e^{-\beta s_M^{(j)2}}ds_M^{(j)}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta}}
 \end{equation}
 \par Λαμβάνοντας τώρα υπόψιν τον ορισμό συνάρτησης πυκνότητας πιθανότητας,      πρέπει $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P\left( s_M^{(j)} \right)ds_M^{(j)}=$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If I replace `thur3.pdf` by `example-image` so I can run the example, then the text in the main body of the document, and the figure caption are all 1lpt (10.95pt) which text do you see being a different size?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle With that very same font? I mean nothing changed?

Comment: yes I just ran your example as posted, but with a generally available image.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok let me edit with a picture so you can see what I mean. Perhaps I am going nuts but I think the text is smaller.

Comment: add `\showoutput` and look for a line that does not look like `\LGR/artemisia/m/it/10.95 n` denoting an 11pt font

Comment: that screen image clearly was _not_ made by the posted code, so isn't that useful.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh I did not know I could check like that. But why do they look uneven to the eye?

Comment: because they are different in the output shown but that isn't related to the code you have posted. You presumably have `\small` somewhere

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is actually exactly one page above since the one from the posted code is breaking the image to the next page etc. But its the same document. Would yoy like the one exactly from the posted code?

Comment: fix your example so other people can run it use `example-image` then check that _that example_ demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is a problem. My document is exactly the way I have the image above but when I load the example image instead of the image I need, it works correctly. Should this be happening?

Comment: You need to post code which produces the problem image. The code you have posted has nothing to do with the image you posted. It isn't even just a question of a different graphic. Your image has figure 7.1. The code you've posted will not label the figure 7.1. It is impossible to tell anything right now because we are completely in the dark about what you are actually doing.

Comment: @cfr This is what I am trying to explain here. The print screen is the code posted. Apart from the label of the figure everything else is the same. The label happens because this is part of my thesis so the code is part of chapter 7. You can see that the text fontsize is smaller than the figure fontsize right? BUT, when I run this piece of code I posted here alone and not as part of the whole thesis, then the problem stands no more. Text fontsize and caption fontsize are the same to the eye. I have no clue what is going on

Comment: @Mitscaype no really you should just remove the image as it doesn't help. there is presumably a font size change in code earlier in your thesis that has leaked out. But you need to make an example that shows that.  You should be able to look back through your thesis and see where the font change starts and then make an example that includes the text from that point on.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok I will remove the image. It happens right from the start of the document. :/ I am kinda desperate because I have the thesis finished and now this happens when I have to deliver

Comment: so you should be able to make an example, the font size is presumably unrelated to the image I would guess you have `\small{hello}` instead of `{\small hello}` somewhere which would make the entire document small except for fixed size things like headings and captions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But it starts even before \mainmatter. It starts while in abstract etc. How to make an example of something that I cannot trace back to show? I looked for \small{} but there is none. If there was one it should be right in the first pages since the font change starts from the scratch...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok you were absolutely right. There was a \footnotesize{} instead of a {\footnotesize } and absoluterly everything was made tiny. I fixed it. I am really gratefull. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font size is presumably unrelated to the image I would guess you have

```
\small{hello}
```

instead of

```
{\small hello}
```

somewhere which would make the entire document small except for fixed size things like headings and captions.